# Disable dialog fragment up when keyboard show

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment

[image]

The pink one is a DialogFragment. When keyboard show, it was going up and overlap the toolbar. How can I make the dialog fragment stay the same and only the edittext go up.

I used SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN or SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE but the fragment still go up

SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING: both dialog and edit text stay the same but I want the edit text go up

Any help will be appreciated?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class HelloDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        if (dialog != null && dialog.getWindow() != null) {
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
            getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true);
            int actionBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(tv.resourceId);
            int statusBarHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.status_bar_height);
            window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
            params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
            params.x = 200 + 2 * Utils.dpToPx(8);
            params.y = statusBarHeight + actionBarHeight + Utils.dpToPx(8);
            params.width = Utils.screenWidth() / 3;
            params.height = Utils.screenHeight() - statusBarHeight - actionBarHeight - 2 * Utils.dpToPx(8);
            window.setAttributes(params);
            dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        }
    }

    static class Utils {

        public static int screenWidth() {
            return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        }

        public static int screenHeight() {
            return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        }

        public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
            return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        }

    }

}
```

dialog_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f2f"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E8E8E8"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chatEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:hint="Enter"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="#B0B0B0"
            android:textDirection="locale"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="SEND"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a tricky to implement it
First, make the Dialog fragment height match parent
Second, add a transparent view at the top of the view (height equal to toolbar). So, when keyboard show, the dialog will be resize but doesn't move up and overlap toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Just to give my idea.

Have you try wrapping all of your elements in `dialog_fragment.xml` by another layout such as `FrameLayout` then set `paddingTop` equal or bigger than the size of `ToolBar`

or

Setting the `marginTop` of the root element equal or bigger than the size of `ToolBar`

I don't if this will help.

Here is  the code of wrapping the element by `FrameLayout`

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:android:paddingTop=toolBarSize/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f2f"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#E8E8E8"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/chatEditText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:hint="Enter"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:textColor="#B0B0B0"
                    android:textDirection="locale"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/sendButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="SEND"
                    android:textColor="#fff"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
     </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What about wrapping all layout with `FrameLayout` and set padding top then setting the `LayoutParams` like this 

  `window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);`

Comment: My dialog must have fixed position, width/height, so whatever the parent is LinearLayout or FrameLayout, it'll be moved up if the softInputMode is SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN or SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE

Comment: Don't know if it help but I edited my post to add code. So that we understand the same thing.